# ¿Qué significan "agora" y "aplico arenas" en este soneto de Quevedo?

Tags: traducción, significado

En una pregunta reciente apareció el siguiente tautograma:

> Antes alegre andaba, agora apenas
>   alcanzó alivio, ardiendo aprisionado;
>   armas a Antandra aumento acobardado;
>   aire abrazo, agua aprieto, aplico arenas.
>      *Francisco de Quevedo*

Tengo duda sobre dos cosas:

- ¿es *agora* una antigua palabra para *ahora*? ([Aquí](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/agora) dice que es judeoespañol. Pero me confunde porque también dice "sustantivo".)
- ¿qué significa *aplico arenas*?

Comment: "Agora" juraría que viene del castellano antiguo y, como tu dices, significa "ahora"

Comment: Sí, viene del castellano antiguo. "Etimología: del castellano antiguo agora, y este del latín hac hora, 'en esta hora'". http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/ahora

Comment: Hum.... para nada está en mi ánimo desmerecer al maestro Quevedo al cual admiro. Pero considerando que está aplicando verbos imposibles de realizar con su sujeto (no es posible abrazar el aire ni apretar el agua), me pregunto si simplemente buscaba un verbo que comenzase con "a" para que concordase con el sustantivo "arenas", el cual a su vez es otra materia elemental (agua, fuego, aire, tierra/arena). Dado que es simplemente una suposición (algo malpensada, huelga decirlo) no me arriegaré a postearlo como respuesta :D

Comment: @Arkana bueno, ¿qué es no posible en la lírica? :) "aire abrazo" se entiende al igual que "agua aprieto". Pero el significado de *aplico arenas* es totalmente turbio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si bien en mi comentario he dicho que podría ser totalmente al azar el uso de la palabra "aplicar" se me ha ocurrido un posible significado metafórico para este caso.

Veamos, tenemos "*agua*", "*aire*" y "*arenas*" los cuales se supone son todo **formas elementales** (agua, aire, fuego y tierra).

Aunque el elemento "*tierra*" es algo ambiguo, normalmente se refiere al suelo, el sustrato, el barro, la roca. Y la arena es también una forma de la tierra (concretamente la forma no cultivable que buscamos muchos en agosto).

Sobre el uso de "aplicar", en este caso parece que nos falta un complemento directo. **Hace falta *algo* a lo que aplicar la arena**, por ejemplo:

> - [[...] se debe aplicar arena fina entre los materiales[...]](http://www.ehowenespanol.com/materiales-entrada-arena-info_367372/).

O bien:

> - Apliqué algo de arena sobre la carta para secar la tinta

(Éste último es un uso un tanto forzado. Normalmente diríamos "eché arena" o "derramé arena").

Dado que Quevedo no nos dice sobré qué aplica la arena, pero la usa en plural, podemos suponer que la aplica sobre más arena. Es decir, echa **arena sobre arena**, como cuando un niño hace un castillo de arena en la playa.

Las construcciones hechas de, o sobre arena, se usan normalmente en parábolas o refranes para mostrar algo que es **inútil de intentar**, que no es consistente o que es imposible.

Por ejemplo:

> - Mis sueños se derrumban como castillos de arena
> - [...]un hombre insensato, que edificó su casa sobre arena. ([Mateo 7:24-27](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mateo%207:24-27&version=RVR1960))

Aquí hay [otros ejemplos](http://www.sabidurias.com/tags/arena/es/7126) de refranes y dichos que usan la construcción o manejo de la arena como algo imposible, fútil o inconstante.

---

Por todo ello, mi teoría es que Quevedo intentaba expresar imposibles:

**Aprieto agua**: Se puede intentar coger un chorro de agua con las manos, pero es inútil, poco menos que imposible, no se mantendrá en nuestras manos, si acaso unas pocas gotas.

**Aire abrazo**: Se pueden cerrar los brazos en torno al viento pero no conseguimos llenar nuestro abrazo. Es otra sensación de futilidad, al igual que en el caso del agua.

**Aplico arena**: Fijándonos en los casos anteriores podríamos deducir que al manipular la arena, o aplicarla sobre más arena no conseguiríamos nada. Podemos intentarlo pero la arena se escurrirá una y otra vez provocando ese mismo sentimiento de inutilidad.

Comment: Interesante, lo de los imposibles sí me lo había más o menos imaginado. Pero no sabía lo referente a la arena. Más aún, lo nuevo para mí y lo que vale más en la respuesta, es la observación de que Quevedo habla de 3 de los "cuatro elementos".

Comment: Gracias por la pregunta, me ha gustado mucho, y además Quevedo es mi poeta favorito. Ha sido un placer disertar sobre su obra. :)

Comment: *Au contraire*! :)